# ROS2 Subscriber create no class

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo,

i cannot correct create subscriber without using classes like in ROS2-Tutorials (Creation of Publisher and subscriber).

I want to migrate my code to ros2 and have a problem by creation of Subscriber.
example of ros1 code :

```
//my callback function
void robot_pose_callback(const geometry_msgs::Pose &call_back_target)
{
do what i want;
}
// in main:
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("robot_pose", 1000,
robot_pose_callback);
```

ROS2 Tutorial use classes, which i dont want to use. ( i dont check it and i dont want to  check it)

in ROS2 it have to be look like :

```
#includes ...

//my callback - Parameter in brackets are wrong ?
void robot_pose_callback(geometry_msgs::msg::Pose::SharedPtr msg)

{
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto move_group_node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("move_group_interface_tutorial");

(Parameter in brackets are wrong)
  auto sub = move_group_node->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Pose>("robot_pose",10, void(robot_pose_callback));
```

the right parameter i can look up on this website :
https://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1node_1_1Node.html#a5c3fe8426e737ff408fd28dea74e54a7

but i dont know what i have to write for :

```
Parameters (create subscriber 1/2 => there is another parameter list 2/2)
    [in]    topic_name  The topic to subscribe on.
    [in]    callback    The user-defined callback function.
    [in]    qos_profile The quality of service profile to pass on to the rmw implementation.
    [in]    group   The callback group for this subscription. NULL for no callback group.
    [in]    ignore_local_publications   True to ignore local publications.
    [in]    msg_mem_strat   The message memory strategy to use for allocating messages.
    [in]    allocator   Optional custom allocator.
```

can somebody show me simple example for this parameter.
Thank you in advice !!!!!!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389488/ros2-subscriber-create-no-class/) by [OlexStup1996](https://answers.ros.org/users/88201/olexstup1996/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this minimal_subscriber example](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/topics/minimal_subscriber/not_composable.cpp) for how to create a subscription without writing a class.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OlexStup1996](https://answers.ros.org/users/88201/olexstup1996/) on 2021-11-03**:
how can i access data in callback? its dont work =( my fail: i cannot use operator "=" for local variable in callback.

```
colcon build:  error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘geometry_msgs::msg::Pose’ {aka ‘geometry_msgs::msg::Pose_<std::allocator<void> >’} and ‘const ConstSharedPtr’ {aka ‘const std::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::msg::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > >’})
   37 |  target_pose1 = call_back_target;
```

my callback:

```
void robot_pose_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Pose::ConstSharedPtr call_back_target)

{

 geometry_msgs::msg::Pose target_pose1;
 target_pose1 = call_back_target;

 //check or change position of target_pose1

 move_group->setPoseTarget(target_pose1);
}
```

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2021-11-03**:
`call_back_target` is a pointer. `target_post1` is not. You need to dereference `call_back_target`:

```
target_pose1 = *call_back_target;
```

**Comment by [OlexStup1996](https://answers.ros.org/users/88201/olexstup1996/) on 2021-11-24**:
Thank you !